# Android: Searching in list. Searching works, but when i click on searched word it redirect to first item on list instead of searched one

Tags: java, android, search

I have problem with app for android. It's a simple dictionary application.
Searching works, but when i click on searched word it redirect to first item on list instead of searched one.

[image: Example]

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
package xxxx;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText filterText;
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    filterText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ListView itemList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    DbBackend dbBackend = new DbBackend(MainActivity.this);
    String[] terms = dbBackend.dictionaryWords();

    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, terms);

    itemList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    itemList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DictionaryActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("DICTIONARY_ID", position);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    filterText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            MainActivity.this.listAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InfoActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

 <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

 <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

What I need to do to get it work?

I think the problem is somewhere in this part of code but I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
itemList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
itemList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,   long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DictionaryActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("DICTIONARY_ID", position);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Thanks

@edit

ActivityDictionary.java:

```
package xxx;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DictionaryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView wordMeaning;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dictionary);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    int dictionaryId = bundle.getInt("DICTIONARY_ID");
    int id = dictionaryId + 1;

    TextView word = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.word);
    wordMeaning = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dictionary);


    DbBackend dbBackend = new DbBackend(DictionaryActivity.this);
    QuizObject allQuizQuestions = dbBackend.getQuizById(id);

    word.setText(allQuizQuestions.getWord());
    wordMeaning.setText(allQuizQuestions.getDefinition());

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_dictionary, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(DictionaryActivity.this, InfoActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Comment: Show `DictionaryActivity` code.

Comment: I added code to main thread

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the position of the clicked item. You need to pass the id of the selected item.

See the code,

```
String selected = terms[position];
// call method in db class to get the id of the selected word
int dbId = dbBackend.getdictionaryWordId(selected);

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DictionaryActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("DICTIONARY_ID", dbId); // pass the id insted of postion
startActivity(intent);
```

I am not sure if the following line is needed in `DictionaryActivity`. Remove the line if it doesn't work.

```
int id = dictionaryId + 1;
```

Comment: Sorry for stupid question but im new in android. I do this code mostly following different tutorials. When i paste your code i get error `Error:(43, 21) error: variable id is already defined in method onItemClick(AdapterView<?>,View,int,long)`

Comment: Now I got `Error:(43, 37) error: cannot find symbol method getdictionaryWordId(String)` at line `int dbId = dbBackend.getdictionaryWordId(selected);`

Comment: You need to implement `getdictionaryWordId` on your own.

Comment: Ok. Much thanks for your help. I will try to figure it out now